# Using TableRowJsonCoder to convert PubSub Message to TableRow in BEAM

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I am using Dataflow 1.9 (JAVA API) to read a Pubsub message and seamlessly stream that into BigQuery without explicitly setting each column in a `TableRow`. Below is the code snippet for the conversion.

```java
PCollection<TableRow> payloadTableRow = pipeline
    .apply("Read",PubsubIO.Read.subscription(***MY_SUBSCRIPTION***)
    .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of()));`
```

The above code works perfectly and I can see the Pubsub message in a topic gets converted to `PCollection<TableRow>` and then into BigQuery using `BigQueryIO.Write`.

When I try to emulate the same in Apache Beam, I couldn't set the `TableRowJsonCoder` for a PubSub message as Beam's `PubSubIO` lacks the method `withCoder()`. In Beam, I tried the `setCoder()` as below but getting compilation error. I even tried `PubsubIO.readStrings` but the error stays same.

```java
pipeline
    .apply("Read",PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
        .fromSubscription(***MY_SUBSCRIPTION***))
    .setCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())`
```

I am seeing the `withCoder()` exists in Dataflow 1.9 but the missing feature impedes me to upgrade to Beam.

My questions are:

- Does Beam's `PubSubIO` class have anything similar to `withCoder()` so that I can move to Beam?
- If so, how can I say `PubSubIO` for this implicit conversion of `TableRowJsonCoder.of()`.
- Would be helpful if I can get to see couple of lines of code snippet for solution in Beam (Java API).

### UPDATE

As Kenn Knowles rightly pointed out, I have used `MapElements` and pulled out the `byte[]` and then transformed that to `TableRow` as below.

```java
    PCollection<byte[]> payloadByteArray = payladInPubSubMessage.apply(
            MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<PubsubMessage, byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public byte[] apply(PubsubMessage input) {
                    return input.getPayload();
                }
            }));

    PCollection<TableRow> payladTableRow = payloadByteArray.apply(
            MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<byte[], TableRow>() {
                @Override
                public TableRow apply(byte[] input) {
                    TableRow tableRow = null;
                    try{
                        tableRow = TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return tableRow;
                }
            }));
```

Now I am encountering `EOFException` while transforming the byte array to TableRow using `TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode()`. I sensed I am missing some sort of `Coder` for `TableRow` and registered a coder as below.

```java
CoderRegistry registry = pipeline.getCoderRegistry();
registry.registerCoderForClass(TableRow.class,TableRowJsonCoder.of());
```

This doesn't seem to solve the issue and I would like to get some insight on the error below:

```java
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.decode(StringUtf8Coder.java:110)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder.decode(TableRowJsonCoder.java:61)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder.decode(TableRowJsonCoder.java:55)
at com.gcp.poc.transformers.TableRowTransformer.processElement(TableRowTransformer.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.readString(StringUtf8Coder.java:63)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.decode(StringUtf8Coder.java:106)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder.decode(TableRowJsonCoder.java:61)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder.decode(TableRowJsonCoder.java:55) .
```

I hope I make sense and would love to get a solution for this decoding issue for TableRow.

Comment: How are you encoding the `TableRow` objects when you write them to Pubsub?

Comment: I hope this is helpful to whomever is reading this: The issue is that TableRowJsonCoder is based on StringUtf8Coder (can be seen in the stack trace). StringUtf8Coder puts the length of the string during the encoding of the string (also applies to the JSon). The PubSub message is probably not encoded with it thus the exception is thrown. I am contemplating on whether to solve this during the publishing or to add something to the pipeline

Answer (score 2):

In Beam, IO connectors are simplified to output their most natural type. For `PubsubIO` it is `PubsubMessage`. From there, you can perform arbitrary processing on the messages.

For your specific example, you would use `PubsubIO.readMessages()` followed by `MapElements` to pull out the `byte[]` payload and parse it to a `TableRow`.

Comment: Updated the question based on your comment. Please enlighten me for the error I am encountering.

Comment: I still don't see your description of how the byte[] messages sent via pubsub are encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The `TableRowJsonCoder` describse how to encode/decode elements of type `TableRow` when passing them between points in a pipeline. Instead of calling `TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode(...)` within your `MapElements`, you should actually examine the bytes that you have received from PubSub, and parse them into some meaningful form. This could be creating a `TableRow` using the various methods for doing so, as shown in the various Beam examples, such as [BigQueryTornadoes](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/BigQueryTornadoes.java#L89).

Comment: I don't want to parse the pubsub byte[] into some model/schema. I am intending to convert the byte[] into TableRow seamlessly. I have fixed the error like `TableRow tableRow = TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode(byteArrayContent, Coder.Context.OUTER);`. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: In these examples, the Table rows are being created manually like `TableRow row = new TableRow().set("column_name", **value**)`. The main reason being my message would be multi-nested and contains alteast 200 elements. I am trying to avoid this boiler-plate code. For the same reason I using `BigQueryUtils.getSchemaFromString(SCHEMA_FILE_FROM_GCS)` and creating schema on the fly.